# Signal Filter Shunt to GND or Virtual GND

Tags: passive-filter, single-supply-op-amp, virtual-ground

In the following two circuits, I am using a TLE2426 as a low impedance virtual ground to bias multiple single supply opamps/diff amps. At the output is an LRC filter, but I'm not sure whether to connect the filter capacitor to GND or virtual ground. My gut says that shunting the unwanted signal frequencies to GND directly is better and would keep them off of the virtual ground line, but I'm not sure if this is correct, or if there's really any difference. Performance-wise I can't distinguish a difference. Which of the two options is better?

Option 1:
[image]

Option 2:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe option 2 is the better one.

Reason being transients being driven out on U2B have a shorter signal path to the ground of the device. If you go with option 1, the transient current need to make their way though the virtual rail driver to ground instead. Obviously a longer path through active devices.

I am however a little surprised there are no capacitors on your virtual ground connecting to the other rails. Various examples on line show some pretty large caps there/

Comment: That confirms what I was thinking. Re the virtual ground caps: I've actually been told that numerous times in response to questions I've posted where I've used a TLE2426 in the schematic, and every time I go back and review the datasheet, and there is no mention anywhere that large caps (or any caps for that matter) are recommended to be used at the output. I have yet to have any obvious issues as a result of not using them, but I'll have to dig into this more.

Comment: The graph on page 17 of the TLE2426 says you may well need some cap on the output if you don't want the thing bursting into oscillation when it has to source current. On past, painful experience it is not wrong. You want to keep out of the region marked unstable at all times.

Comment: @User7251 yes I looked at the datasheet too, and expected to see recommendations there. That's why I said I was surprised. However, I think that is just an error on the writers part. It makes sense to have one or better two. Also, Dan's experience indicates it is more crucial. If you were using the 8 pin part with the noise reduction cap it might be different.

Comment: @DanMills, right I was looking at that figure, and some previous posts discussing this, and it does seem to be general consensus to use larger caps from the +/- rails to virtual ground to avoid that unstable region. I'm drawing very little current in the above application <1mA but I should probably consider this ... what happened in your application?

Comment: @Trevor, the version I'm using is actually the 8-pin NR version, with 100nF and 1uF caps to ground on that pin. In the data tables they commonly used 1uF and I think I tested this a while back and found that that combination gave me the best noise reduction. But the schematic on page 3 suggests that the NR pin is at the input rather than output, suggesting that the NR caps aren't a substitute for the load capacitance you and Dan have suggested

Comment: They are not a substitute as they provide filtering to the voltage divider not capacitive load to the output driver (Which is weird, but seem to be what that part likes).